# Unite string by n-multiple of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column with a number of rows.
I want to row-combine the string based on a given multiple.

```
have <- tibble(id = tolower(stri_rand_strings(10, 3)))

> have
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   id   
   <chr>
 1 6kk  
 2 zcd  
 3 dlr  
 4 wt2  
 5 lej  
 6 hir  
 7 6ye  
 8 e4v  
 9 9op  
10 b4u 

# concatenate every 2 rows consecutively with sep '#'
want_multiple_2
  <chr>                                                             
1 17t#opl                                                           
2 zr5#d4x                                                           
3 dw2#xnx                                                           
4 fcr#sdc                                                           
5 ...
```

I want to be able to parameterize the number of multiple so that it's flexible enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 5
sep = "#"
have %>%
   group_by(grp=gl(nrow(.), n, nrow(.))) %>%
   summarise(result = str_c(id, collapse = sep), .groups="drop")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `stringr` library, we can try matching on the patterns `[A-Z]{1,2}` and `[A-Z]{1,5}`:

```r
input <- paste(LETTERS, collapse="")
want_multiple_2 <- str_extract(input, "[A-Z]{1,2}")
want_multiple_2
want_multiple_5 <- str_extract(input, "[A-Z]{1,5}")
want_multiple_5

[1] "AB" "CD" "EF" "GH" "IJ" "KL" "MN" "OP" "QR" "ST" "UV" "WX" "YZ"
[1] "ABCDE" "FGHIJ" "KLMNO" "PQRST" "UVWXY" "Z"
```

Comment: The actual data `ID` is not necessarily the letters. I'm just using the `LETTERS` for a quick reproducible data. For example the IDs are like `c('TREX0001101, 'TRAM010131',...)`, for multiple 2 combination, this would give me `c('TREX0001101TRAM010131', '...')`. I think I should clarify that I want to have control on the separation. So it would be `c('TREX0001101#TRAM010131', '...')`

Comment: @AfiqJohari Not sure I follow, but generally you should give us sample data which reflects your actual problem.

Comment: Got it, let me give a better reproducible example